Is any (integrable) centered, adapted stochastic process with independent increments a martingale?
I came across the following question:
Assume $(X(t), t\geq 0)$ is an integrable, adapted stochastic process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t, t\geq 0), \mathbb{P})$ with independent increments. Assume further, $\mathbb{E}(X(t))=c$ for all $t\geq0$ for a constant $c$ (w.o.l.g. $c=0$). Is $X$ a martingale?
This is obviously true if the filtration is the $\textbf{natural}$ filtration:
For $t\geq s$ we get
$$\mathbb{E}(X(t)|\mathcal{F}_s) = \mathbb{E}(X(t)-X(s)|\mathcal{F}_s) + \mathbb{E}(X(s)|\mathcal{F}_s) =X(s)$$
using the independence of the increments together with the fact that the expectation is constant and $X(s)$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable.
My question is: does it also hold for a general filtration (to which $X$ is adapted)? In my opinion it boils down to the question if the increment $X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$.
Thanks in advance!

You are correct. The key is that $X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.

Take any independent increment process, say BM, on $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$  and consider the new filtration $(\mathcal F'_t)$ defined by $\mathcal F'_t=\mathcal F$ for all $t$. The process is adapted to this  filtration and martinagle property says that $X_t=X_s$ a.s for $t\ge s$, which is false.

Of course. Thanks a lot!
